# Click event of CButtonColumn

Tags: php, yii, onclick, yii-events

I am new to yii framework. I have spent a lot research about my problem, and I followed the tutorial on [link](https://gist.github.com/luislobo/5979360#file-cgridview-with-cbuttoncolumns) and it did not work, my `CButtonColumn` could not call `js function`.

Hope anyone help me.

Regards,
Manohar

Comment: show your code please

Answer (score 0):

The code you linked looks good. Here is the distilled version:

```
'columns'=>[
    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    'template'=>'{view}',
    'buttons'=>[
        'view'=>['click'=>'some_js_function']
    ]
]
```

Relevant information: [CButtonColumn#buttons-detail](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn#buttons-detail)

Do you get any js-errors perhaps? If you are using ajax, as in the link you gave, check the network-tab (in chrome developer tools or similar) and see if the page request is being made.